# Storing login cookies when closed the browser

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to store login cookies to web browser my script when closed the web browser i have to login back i want to prevent it. I want to store login cookies. Anyone can help me thanks

Here is my code

```
setcookie('uid', $uid, time()+60*30);
setcookie('username ', $username , time()+60*30);
setcookie('email', $email, time()+60*30);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you made sure that your browser or an addon doesn't remove cookies after a session or you aren't using Incognito mode?

Comment: Where is the part that actually checks if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the time you set for the cookie to last is small 60 * 30 seconds is 30minutes.
That means your user will need to login again every 30minutes try: 60* 60*24 *30 for a month before the cookie expires

```
setcookie('uid', $uid, time()+60*60* 24 *30);
setcookie('username ', $username , time()+60*60* 24 *30);
setcookie('email', $email, time()+60*60* 24 *30);
```

Comment: I checked your script but i have to login again when closed the web browser

Comment: go to your browser settings and check if the cookie is there: on chrome go to: settings -> cookies and other site data -> 'name of your site' -> 'name of cookie'

Comment: How to add one year expire cookies

Comment: use  60 * 60* 24 * 30 * 12  that is roughly one year

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **session_set_cookie_params()** before session_start();

```
session_set_cookie_params(SET_TIME_IN_SECONDS,"/");
session_start();
```

The '/' represents the session will last all paths for the domain.

Comment: I added but when I closed ther browse i have to login again

Comment: Are your login page header has scripted for redirection if session data exist? For example `if($_SESSION['user_id'] != null) {header("location:home.php");}`